# Pass Commands to a Server with C++

Tags: android, c++, http, opencv, cgi

I am working on a project utilizes an Android tablet/smartphone as an IP Camera and uses Open CV to process that video feed on a Windows PC.  I want to be able to send data back to the phone application depending on the results of the image processing.  I have managed to get on to the IP Camera Server URL and post data to the phone by submitting a simple HTML form, but I do not know how to pass data to that form and submit it through C++ (nor do I know if this is even a good method of doing this).  I would not consider myself an expert in C++ by any means,  and a lot of the resources I could find online were confusing.

If you need any of the code from my app, html page, or C++ code just ask!  It would be a lot to put up and I do not know what would help.

Thanks a million!

Comment: You may need to implement a client-server using socket to communicate between your tab and pc.

Comment: @Haris Ok so I have looked around a few hours now and can't find any kind of "sockets for dummies" tutorials with C++.  Any kind of further guidance? Some basic example code or a resource where I can download the library and it is explained to me?  Thanks!

Comment: You can start with this link http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm where it's well explained client-server with example.

Comment: @Haris I dont see anywhere that shows how to get the library.  At first I figuered this meant thatsocket is a standard library but my C++ doesn't recognize the header file.  I am working on Visual C++ 2010 on a Windows 7 machine if that helps at all.

Comment: That tutorial is for Linux. You should have to look on socket programming in windows like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13071/Programming-Windows-TCP-Sockets-in-C-for-the-Begin, http://blog.pusheax.com/2013/07/windows-api-winsock-create-your-first.html

Comment: As a followup to anyone else looking at this, we ended up using cURL - works great!